# yii framework backend product page not display

Tags: yii, frameworks

When i open a backend of the website and click on product it gives this error

**error 1:**

```
date() [<a href='function.date'>function.date</a>]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CDT/-5.0/DST' instead
```

**error 2:**

```
public function actions()
   {
  return array(
            'uploadManufacLogo' => 'application.controllers.upload.ManuLogoUploadAction',
            'uploadDesignerLogo' => 'application.controllers.upload.DesigLogoUploadAction',
             'uploadProductImage' => 'application.controllers.upload.ProductImageUploadAction',
        );
     }
     public function init(){
         $this->_start_date                =    date("Y-m-d");
         $this->_end_date                =    date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+60 days"));
     }
     /**
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to put the timezone in a configuration line in your php.ini file. You should have a block like this in your php.ini file:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

After configuring, make sure to restart httpd `service httpd restart`.